# CGImage.cropping(to:) adding one pixel in height

Tags: ios, swift, crop, cgimage

My code looks like this-

```
if let cgImage = cgImage.cropping(to: cropRect) {
   let croppedUIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: 1.0, orientation: originalImage.imageOrientation)
   return croppedUIImage // Control was here while doing all "po"s
}
```

And then I printed few objects on console-

```
(lldb) po cropRect
▿ (408.0, 0.0, 2448.0, 2448.0)
  ▿ origin : (408.0, 0.0)
    - x : 408.0
    - y : 0.0
  ▿ size : (2448.0, 2448.0)
    - width : 2448.0
    - height : 2448.0

(lldb) po cgImage.height
2448

(lldb) po cgImage.width
2449

(lldb) po croppedUIImage.size
▿ (2448.0, 2449.0)
  - width : 2448.0
  - height : 2449.0
```

My cropRect is of size 2448.0 by 2448.0 but `cropping(to:)`s output image has size of 2448.0 by 2449.0

Why so? and how can I solve this without cropping the image again?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same issue

Comment: Not actually...Still looking for solution...but it seems the problem is not so common.